# Is there any equivalent of Asset.fail(message) in WebdriverIO expect assertions

Tags: webdriver, assert

Is there any equivalent of `Asset.fail(message)` of TestNG in WebdriverIO expect assertions.

I need to explicitly fail the test in catch block by passing the exception error message.

I didn't find any such in the WebdriverIO Expect documentation.

Comment: Why don't you just not catch the error?